# R Markdown no imprime Tabla de Contenido

Tags: r, markdown

Estoy usando R 3.6.0 y RStudio 1.2.1335 (nuevas versiones) en mi PC con Windows 10 e intentando crear una presentación en Beamer usando RMarkdown. El problema es que luego de correr el código, se crea una presentación pero con la página de Tabla de Contenidos en blanco. Mi código funciona perfectamente en RStudio Cloud. Sin embargo, cuando intento correr el mismo código en mi versión instalada de RStudio, no recibo ningún mensaje de error y la tabla de contenidos aparece en blanco.

Ya intenté todo: reinstalando R y RStudio (y también con versiones anteriores), desactualizando algunas actualizaciones de Windows recientes, reinstalando MikTex, y nada parece funcionar. De nuevo, mi código funciona perfectamente en RStudio Cloud (allí sí puedo ver la tabla de contenido con los hipervínculos) pero no así en mi versión instalada en la PC.

El código en RMarkdown sería el siguiente:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Guillermo"
date: "21/5/2019"
output: beamer_presentation
toc: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

# R Markdown

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple 
formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word 
documents. For more details on using R Markdown see 
<http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be 
generated that includes both content as well as the output 
of any embedded R code chunks within the document.
````

Este problema me está volviendo loco. Solamente necesitaría ideas de qué probar para lograr que la tabla de contenidos aparezca.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba el siguiente encabezado:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Guillermo"
date: "21/5/2019"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    toc: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
---
```

Cambios:

- El principal, usamos `xelatex` para generar el PDF en reemplazo de  `pdflatex`
- Los parámetros `toc` y `latex_engine` los hacemos hijos de `beamer_presentation`

En un entorno similar al tuyo fue la única forma que me genere la tabla de contenidos, no tengo una respuesta por que con `pdflatex` no funciona esto.

Comment: Wow! Funcionó! Muchísimas gracias! Estuve días con este problema! Muchas gracias!